# sequelize hangs in nested eager query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have three models:

- Location
- Visitor
- Ticket

In my initialization I have these associations:

```
Location.hasMany(Visitor,{as:'visitors'});
Location.hasMany(Ticket,{as:"tickets"});

Visitor.belongsTo(Location);
Visitor.hasMany(Ticket,{as:"tickets"});

Ticket.belongsTo(Visitor);
Ticket.belongsTo(Location);
```

The following query works allright:

```
  Location.findAll({
    attributes:['id','name'],
    include:[
      {
        model: Visitor,
        as:'visitors', 
        attributes: ["id"],
      },
    ]   
  })
```

Now if I include Tickets in the Visitor  ...

```
  Location.findAll({
    attributes:['id','name'],
    include:[
      {
        model: Visitor,
        as:'visitors', 
        attributes: ["id"],
        include:{
          model:Ticket,
          as:'tickets',
          attributes:["id"],
        }
      },
    ]   
  })
```

or if I include Tickets with in the Location ...

```
  Location.findAll({
    attributes:['id','name'],
    include:[
      {
        model: Visitor,
        as:'visitors', 
        attributes: ["id"],
      },
      {
        model: Ticket,
        as: 'tickets',
      }
    ]   
  })
```

... the query hangs and does not come back, i.e. the Promise returned by findAll() does not resolve.

Any idea would be much appreciated. I am scratching my head on this.
BTW, my sequelize version according to package.json is 5.21.5.
Cheers, Andreas

Comment: What does "does not come back." mean? Any errors? Does the query "hang" in the Database process list? And... Which database system is it?

Comment: No, it just hangs. The Promise doesn't resolve.

Comment: Sorry, just realized my first version of the question had some wrong code in there. Bummer ...

Comment: So the issue was resolved?

Comment: NO, it was not resolved. I changed the code above. My example of the working code was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I boiled it down to model.js of sequelizer in line 715. 
[image]
Here the resulting message is "Visitor is not associated to Visitor!. 
Howevery, I don't understand how Sequelizer comes to this understanding and why it caueses an error. By the way, the Error doesn't surface, I don't know why. It is escalated to util.js of bluebird but not to my catch() in Promise-chain.